# How to reindex with MultiIndex?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, multi-index

I've got a DataFrame like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'var1': {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 0.0,
  6: 0.0,
  7: 0.0,
  8: 0.0,
  10: 0.0},
 'var2': {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 0.0,
  6: 0.0,
  7: 0.0,
  8: 0.0,
  10: 0.0},
 'var3': {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 0.0,
  6: 0.0,
  7: 0.0,
  8: 0.0,
  10: 0.0},
 'var4': {0: 0.0,
  1: 0.0,
  2: 0.0,
  3: 0.0,
  4: 0.0,
  6: 0.0,
  7: 0.0,
  8: 0.0,
  10: 0.0}})
```

And I'd like to fill the missing indices, so I used `.reindex` first:

```
df.reindex(np.arange(1, 11))
```

And I got:

```
    var1    var2    var3    var4
1   0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
2   0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
3   0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
4   0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
5   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
6   0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
7   0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
8   0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
9   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
10  0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
```

However, I need to keep track of multiple indices and when I tried to construct MultiIndex and pass it to `.reindex` it didn't work as I was expecting it to:

```
    df.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["A"], np.arange(1, 11)]))

        var1    var2    var3    var4
A   1   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
    2   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
    3   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
    4   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
    5   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
    6   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
    7   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
    8   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
    9   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
   10   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

I can't really understand what's going on here and the documentation of `.reindex` is not quite clear to me. Can someone advise me on this and tell why MultiIndex can't be passed to `.reindex` or what am I doing wrong?

### @Edit:

**@jazrael** provided a good solution when we move from 1-level to 2-level MultiIndex. However, what about a case when we want to reindex from 2-level MultiIndex to 3-level MultiIndex?

E.g.:

```
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([np.repeat([1, 2], [4, 5]), df.index])

        var1    var2    var3    var4
1   0   0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
    1   0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
    2   0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
    3   0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
2   4   0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
    6   0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
    7   0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
    8   0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
   10   0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
```

And I'd like to get:

```
            var1    var2    var3    var4
A   1   0   0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
        1   0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
        2   0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
        3   0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
    2   4   0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
        5   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
        6   0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
        7   0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
        8   0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
        9   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
       10   0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
```

Comment: what is the end use of this reindex with an extra level? is it because you are going to concat several dataframes?

Comment: @Ben.T Yes. I need to keep track of the currently processed subset to concatenate them later.

Comment: If you're concatenating using `pd.concat` you can either use a dictionary or the `keys` argument to keep track of your `Frame or Series` objects put into concatenation.

Answer (score 3):

Because want use `reindex` for simple, not `MultiIndex` index is necessary set `level=1` for match second level of new `MultiIndex`:

```
df = df.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["A"], np.arange(1, 11)]), level=1)
print (df)
      var1  var2  var3  var4
A 1    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
  2    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
  3    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
  4    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
  5    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
  6    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
  7    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
  8    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
  9    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
  10   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you elaborate on the explanation though? I can't really understand how this solution works. According to my understanding, my MultiIndex is already of the same length as `np.arange(1, 11)`

Comment: @Xaume - In dataframe is index created by  numbers, new passed MultiIndex is created by `A`in first level and numbers in second level. So need match numbers between original index and second level of new MultiIndex, it means need reindex says use second level for reindex by passing `level=1`.

Comment: @Xaume - Maybe for better understanding help samples from docs ? [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) ?

Comment: @Xaume - If still something no clear let me know, I try explain more.

Comment: Unfortunetely, docs don't have an use case of level attribute and I'm still struggling to understand how this works. Especially now when I hit the case where my `df` has MultiIndex with 2 levels and I'm trying to reindex it with 3-level MultiIndex - `level=1` doesn't work anymore (as well as something like `level=[1,2]`). Please see my **@edit** for the example.

Comment: @Xaume - hmmm, tested and got error `TypeError: Join on level between two MultiIndex objects is ambiguous`, so now pandas support only reindex 1 level to many levels or same number levels to same number levels of MultiIndex. Many levels to many levels failed.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new index with the extra level and perform an explicit DataFrame join to get what you want.

```
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([np.repeat([1, 2], [4, 5]), df.index], names=["key1", "key2"])
# If df's index is already created, do df.rename_axis(["key1", "key2"], inplace=True)

new_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['A']*11, np.repeat([1, 2], [4, 7]), range(11)],
                                       names=["new_key", *df.index.names])
output = pd.DataFrame([], index=new_index).join(df, on=df.index.names)  # Join on overlapped index levels based on names
```

Output:

```
                   var1  var2  var3  var4
new_key key1 key2                        
A       1    0      0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
             1      0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
             2      0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
             3      0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
        2    4      0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
             5      NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
             6      0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
             7      0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
             8      0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
             9      NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
             10     0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
```